# How to opposite Select From a Bit Value in SQL without Use Case when

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I Want to Select opposite  Value of AbsenceStatus in tsql ,

> AbsenceStatus DataType is Bit

```
SELECT 
    [Date],
    NOT(AbsenceStatus) As IsWorkday 
FROM 
    tkp_DailyStatistics
```

Comment: `bit` isn't a Boolean; you can't treat it like one. `NOT(1)` doesn't mean anything to the RDBMS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `-`:

```
select 1 - b
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=95b3e191e3a5bd95191a12625447d5e3) is a db<>fiddle.

Note:  This converts the value to a number, so you might really want:

```
select convert(bit, 1 - b)
```

Answer (score 0):

In addition to Gordon's answer +1, we could also try using the modulus here:

```
SELECT
    [Date],
    (AbsenceStatus + 1) % 2 AS IsWorkday
FROM tkp_DailyStatistics;
```

This logic works because a zero absent status becomes 1, while a 1 absent status gets incremented to 2, but then the modulus takes it back to zero.

### Demo